# Firebase Emulator - Suppress "Loaded functions definitions from source"

Tags: firebase, logging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am running firebase functions on local emulator and with the latest version of `firebase-tools`, I get this message repeatedly (It impacts my ability to debug). Is there a way to suppress this message.

```
+  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: v1.function1, v1.function2, v1.function3.
```

[image]

I am using the following npm package versions

- "firebase-admin": "^11.0.0"
- "firebase-functions": "^4.0.2"
- "firebase-tools": "^11.16.0"

Comment: You can try [Emulator Suite UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/emulator-suite) to add filters to show only error level logs.

Comment: I will need other logs (info incl.) from the cloud functions. I just want this to be suppressed. Right now, I get this message every 10 seconds, that I cannot look for other logs from the functions.